# Generating Thumbnail Image issue, hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime always returns NO

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to generate thumbnail from mp4 file which is part of Xcode project. I have success in generating thumbnails from Mp4 using the ThumbGenerator class, but it failed to generate Thumbnail for m3u8 file. So, I am trying a slightly different approach to generate Thumbnail in which I take the pixel buffer output from the AVPlayer and convert it into UIImage.I have a created a GitHub Repo for the sample project: https://github.com/dep2k/VideoThumbnail.git

In the ViewDidLoad, I call the load method to create AVPlayer and load video.

```
-(void)load {

    NSURL * url = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"mp4"];

    self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];

    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    layer.frame = self.view.frame;
    layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

    [self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.status"                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:kStatusDidChangeKVO];

    [self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.loadedTimeRanges"            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:kTimeRangesKVO];

}
```

In the player observer method, I have the code to generate thumbnail:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)inKeyPath ofObject:(id)inObject change:(NSDictionary*)inChange context:(void*)inContext
{
    if (inContext == kStatusDidChangeKVO){
        AVPlayerItemStatus status = self.player.currentItem.status;

        if (status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay && self.player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {

            if(!self.isPlaying){
                self.isPlaying = true;
                self.player.rate = 1.0;
                self.player.muted = YES;

                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 4 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self generateThumb];
                });
            }

        }
    } else if (inContext == kTimeRangesKVO){
        NSArray *timeRanges = (NSArray *)[inChange objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        NSLog(@"Time Ranges");
    }

}
```

Finally, to generate thumbnail I have the following code:

```
-(void)generateThumb {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

        NSDictionary* settings = @{ (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] };
        self.output = [[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:settings];
        [self.player.currentItem addOutput:self.output];

        CMTime vTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(90000, 90000);
        BOOL foundFrame = [self.output hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:vTime];
        if(foundFrame){

            CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
            CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [self.output copyPixelBufferForItemTime:vTime itemTimeForDisplay:nil];
            CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];

            CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                                     createCGImage:ciImage
                                     fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                         288,
                                                         192)];

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:videoImage];
            CGImageRelease(videoImage);
            NSLog(@"FrameFound");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"FrameNotFound");
        }
    });

}
```

hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime method always returns NO, even when player is successfully playing the video.